# Beginner in C: Why does "0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3" return false, but "1 + 2 == 3.0" returns true?

Tags: c, types, expression

I think I understand why `0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3` returns 0: Because `0.1 + 0.2` output a double type, which `0.3` isn't...right?

Then why does `1 + 2 == 3.0` return 1 if the expression has different types?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{

  printf("0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3: %d\n", 0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3); // returns 0 (false).                                    
  printf("1 + 2 == 3.0: %d\n", 1 + 2 == 3.0);         // returns 1 (true) 
  
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because it is not possible to represent tenths precisely with binary floating point arithmetic, but integers can be represented accurately (for a large range of values).

Comment: chickpea, "Because 0.1 + 0.2 output a double type, which 0.3 isn't...right?" --> No.   `double` can encode exactly about 2^64 different values.  0.1, 0.2, and 0.3 are **not** in that set.  What  nearby values do you think the program uses?